# Filter first value of Attribute List in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

For all employees of our company, who left the company, we set the attribute `msExchExtensionCustomAttribute1` to the date, when the employee will leave the company.

[image: The "msExchExtensionCustomAttribute1" is a list attribute]

I would like to get all AD users with `Get-ADUser`, where the first value of the list is set and the date value of the first value in the attribute is younger than the current date.
How can i achieve this with Powershell? With Filter?

I tried this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {msExchExtensionCustomAttribute1 -gt Get-Date}
```

but i got an ADFilterPArsingException

Comment: Well what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please take a look at [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | ?{$_.msExchExtensionCustomAttribute1} | ?{[datetime]::ParseExact($_.msExchExtensionCustomAttribute1, "dd.MM.yyyy", $null) -lt (get-date)}
```